# What considerations need to be taken when building a lakefront property?

Tags: construction, new-home, flooding, building

I'm in the process of evaluating a lake-front lot in my city in hopes of building my next home there. The lot is on a small peninsula as seen on google maps [here](https://goo.gl/maps/Ld14BaGRJoH2).

I briefly talked to a friend of mine who does home construction and he said the water table is high and that I likely wouldn't be able to have a traditional basement (something I would very much prefer to have). I'm wonder what other considerations I would need to take. Would it be standard to consult with a builder before even purchasing land?

Comment: This is a fairly broad question that goes a bit beyond "DIY home improvement". Yes, you should consult with local experts including builders and city engineers or inspectors. I'd also reconsider posting your home's location on a highly visible public network.

Comment: With all the flooded out lake-front properties these days, you are entering into a bit of a gamble with this kind of property. If you are going to go there... build it high.

Comment: FWIW, this isn't my home's location, or even a property I own. It is approximate coordinates of a lot I'm simply looking at.

Comment: Well the end point of the approximate location on that peninsula looks pretty well built out. Having seen and known Lake Monona it seems that most empty lots were snarfed up many years ago. Are you looking at some lot with an old shack that you would intend to raze and replace with a new structure?

Comment: Yes, that is what I’d like to do.

Comment: you can have a basement with a high water table, it's just going to be more expensive to prepare and maintain the site.

Comment: Agree with the builder about the basement. Beyond that (if you have the time), I'd have a brief sit-down with a local architect to see if the lot makes sense for what you want.